# How to recognize the Integer in a column using Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have a excel sheet where I have mentioned few tag names along the side of the serial numbers. Is it possible using excel vba to identify the Integer values in the given column and make the corresponding tag names Bold.

[image: This is how the sheet looks like initially]

[image: This is how the sheet looks like Once after the making the font bold]

Comment: Use conditional formatting with formula like `=int(A1)=A1`

Comment: `2.3` isn't an *integer* value...

Comment: It's pretty simple VBA. Concept: a loop going thru all cells in the 2nd column, if not empty, look at cell of left, check if it does NOT have a decimal in it's `.Text` property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use following sub. I tested it and found working.

```
    Sub fBold()
        Dim UsedCell, MyRange, srcIdentifier

        UsedCell = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 1).SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Row
        Set MyRange = Range("A1:A" & UsedCell)
        For Each intCell In MyRange
            If Not InStr(1, intCell.Value, ".") > 0 Then
                intCell.Offset(0, 1).Font.Bold = True
            End If
        Next
    End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a ton, its working just as I expected. Have a great day ahead mate.